# Click on button with <href> and <a> tag

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, safari, automation

I am trying to click on a "Verify Now" button which is nested inside the  tag and . I cannot directly navigate to href link since, each link every time has a different token to activate and which is why I am proceeding to rather click on it.

PFB the html
[image]

```
<a href="http://click1.clickrouter.com/redirect?token=a2258079c24c4c50a56b6b1ffb75d6e2&amp;url=https%3A//sequoia-api-staging-write.ymedia.in/write/api/v1/contact/activate_account%3FtempSignupToken%3D9190c8f7-70e7-4b4f-a915-2d4498eb7c32" style="text-decoration: none ; color: white" target="_other" rel="nofollow">Verify Now</a>
```

Please can somebody help me with the code? I have tried the below codes, but still doesnt help. Not sure, whats missing.

```
@Selenium_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[contains(text(), 'Verify Now')]")

@Selenium_driver.find_element(:css, ".Verify.Now").click

@Selenium_driver.find_element(:link_text, "Verify Now").click
```

Also, the page source for that email body in iframe as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:800px;clear:both;margin-bottom: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <iframe id="publicshowmaildivcontent" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 0;">
                          EMAIL BODY
                      </iframe>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath for your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Verify Now')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Is there a way to click with partial href?

Answer (score 0):

**Modified the answer:**

```
@Selenium_driver.switch_to.frame("publicshowmaildivcontent") 
@Selenium_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(), 'Verify Now')]").click
```

**or you can do:**

```
@Selenium_driver.switch_to.frame("publicshowmaildivcontent") 
@Selenium_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href, 'http://click1.clickrouter.com/')]").click
```

**//Try clicking by javascript:**

```
@Selenium_driver.switch_to.frame("publicshowmaildivcontent") 

@element = @Selenium_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href, 'http://click1.clickrouter.com/')]");

@Selenium_driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",@element);
```

Comment: Checking..... with the second option. The first one you said is also suggested by @RNS and didnt work. `@Selenium_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(), 'Verify Now')]")

Comment: Can you check whether your element is in the iframe?

Comment: I dont see any tag with text <iframe> in the inspector. Is there some other way to find out?

Comment: Hey, i just saw in the page_source, that this EMAIL BODY is inside the iframe.

Comment: `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:800px;clear:both;margin-bottom: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <iframe id="publicshowmaildivcontent" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 0;">
                          EMAIL BODY
                      </iframe>`

Comment: Please switch to iframe first and then you can find the element

Comment: Yes.. Trying it!

Comment: It switches to iframe and appears to click on something apart from the button !

Comment: `@Selenium_driver.switch_to.frame('publicshowmaildivcontent')
#button = @Selenium_driver.find_element(:link_text, "Verify Now")`

Also tried the same with xpath.. Now trying with

`button = switch_to.frame(@Selenium_driver.find‌​_element_by_xpath(:x‌‌​​path, "//iframe[@nam‌​e='Verify Now']"))
button.click`

Comment: These appears to click somewhere, but doesnt click on the element! Strange.

Comment: Do we need to give `switch_to.frame` and the `find_element` in the same line of code

Comment: I am trying to have the code in the same line.  `iframe = @Selenium_driver.switch_to.frame("publicshowmaildivcontent")
  iframe.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(), 'Verify Now')]").click`

Comment: You are following the incorrect approach. Did you try the code given by me.

Comment: Yes, I did. Both of the codes with exactly how you gave, which appears to be clicking somewhere apart from the button and passing the tests.

Comment: Try putting a little wait for checking which element is being clicked.

Comment: I am..! Moreover, there are no clickable elements apart from this button... and the page doesn't appear to navigate to anywhere.

Comment: I see now it is navigating to that element location like automatically scrolling down to the button, but doesnt appear to click on that button

Comment: Adding sleep between the `switch_frame` and `find_element` is bad?

Comment: You can do for debug purpose.

Comment: it goes to the element location, says, it has clicked(but dont notice the click and new tab opened) . 

PS: I am doing it for mobile browser in safari.

Comment: If your new tab is opening you can switch to the new tab and if your click doesn't work, you can use javascript click. I have updated the code again

Comment: No. The new tab is not opening since it is not clicking on the button.

Comment: Like I said, it appears to find the element, and it clicks not on the button but somewhere else and validates the click and passes

Comment: I am using ruby client.

Comment: You can click on any element in selenium using JavaScript. I have added the code for you.

Comment: I ll try, I am not familar with javascript . Is this correct? `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor);driver; `  Without the semicolon or comma before the `driver;` it throws an error .

Comment: Moreover `JavascriptExecutor` Wont I need to define this? and have the necessary set up? Will just adding this code work?

Comment: `uninitialized constant JavascriptExecutor (NameError)`

Comment: Can you share your URL please

Comment: You can navigate to `mailinator.com` in your mobile and enter `rosario.cage1536@mailinator.com` to find the mystery(Verify Now) button that never clicks.

Comment: That is a secure site.

Comment: I am already navigating inside the site, clicking on the email tab and reaching the email body, and I am also able to fetch the texts existing. Is only the button secure?

Comment: Are you able to do it in your system.

Comment: The tests pass, but I dont see the click happening !

Comment: Monika I just wanted you to have a look at the page source which salenium is seeing actually. If you can tell me whether I can do this or not then it would be really helpful.
`<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:800px;clear:both;margin-bottom: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <iframe id="publicshowmaildivcontent" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 0;">
                          EMAIL BODY
                      </iframe>
                  </div>`

Comment: I don't see Verify Now in this iframe.